# Run Dockerfile on Raspberry Pi after every push into a GitHub Repo

Tags: docker, automation, raspberry-pi, github-actions

I'm not sure what stack exchange this post would fit in so if this belongs somewhere else let me know.

I'm trying to connect my Raspberry Pi to my repository on GitHub. What I want to happen is that everytime I push something to the repository, a Docker instance starts running on the R-Pi.

I thought the way to go would be to setup a webhook on GitHub Actions and putting my R-Pi's public IP as the target url. I have a port exposed on my router for the R-Pi. If it got a GitHub request on the port then it would execute said Docker instance. I tried using NGINX and NGROK but it just wasn't working. Do you guys have any insights?

Answer (score 0):

On your Raspberry Pi, you must have something running that will serve as a gateway for github requests. To automate the container build and deployment, I advise using Jenkins and the generic trigger plugin.

In order to listen for remote repository changes, you must create a Jenkins pipeline and enable the generic trigger plugin.